# Is there a tool to convert a .vim colour definition file to use in VS.NET 2008

Tags: visual-studio, vim, syntax-highlighting

If you go to a site such as:

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~maverick/VimColorSchemeTest/index-c.html

It has a bunch of example colour themes for VI.

Does anyone know of a tool that would take those files and convert them into .vssettings files to use in Visual Studio?

If not, how about some good docs on ether of the formats.

Comment: That would be handy - having to eyeball my favourite vim themes in VS is painful!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Visual Studio theme generator which may help.

http://frickinsweet.com/tools/Theme.mvc.aspx